# Fastest way to compress video on Android with ffmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, whatsapp

I'm using ffmpeg to lower the filesize of a video on Android.

I'm using this command.

"-i input -crf 28 -vf scale='if(gt(iw,ih),640,trunc(oh*a/2)*2)':'if(gt(iw,ih),trunc(ow/a/2)*2,640)' -acodec copy -preset ultrafast -tune fastdecode -tune zerolatency output"

The time to compress this video is twice the duration of the video. (1 minute video = 2 minute time to convert) Is there a way to speed this conversion up?

Whatsapp seems to do it at almost a 1:1 ratio (time to encode:duration of video).

Comment: Have you found any answer for this?

Comment: I used the standard media extractor stuff on Android but it's still slow compared to whatsapp.

Comment: Are you handling with api 16 devices? I'm having some problems with them.

Comment: I just went with api 18 and above.

Comment: Hi sir, did you find any solution for this problem, if yes please share it, I also have the same problem. Thanks